# Get date part of date time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have web api controller where I need to write date to table.

I try to do it like this

```
[ResponseType(typeof(TimeTable))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostStartPause(TimeTable startPause)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Date; 
            TimeTable c = (from x in db.TimeTables
                where x.Company == startPause.Company && x.INN == startPause.INN
                select x).First();
            c.StartPause = startPause.StartPause;
            c.Today = dt;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        //db.TimeTables.Add(startPause);
        //db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
        // return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startPause.Id }, startPause);
    }
```

For date part I try to use this code

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Date;
```

But it writes date and time

Here is TimeTable class

```
 public partial class TimeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string INN { get; set; }
    public string StartDay { get; set; }
    public string StartPause { get; set; }
    public string EndDay { get; set; }
    public string EndPause { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Today { get; set; }
}
```

How I can write only date to db?

Comment: Because a `DateTime` always has a time component. If you want to store the value in the db without a 'time', make the field `DATE` type (SqlServer)

Comment: Is that `Today` column in database set to `datetime` type? Try change it to just `date` (C# only has `DateTime`).

Comment: Or you could just convert it to a string `DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); // case sensitive` and then write a trigger in Sql Server to deal with that i.e make the reverse conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your table schema on DB server, apparently the field datatype is set to [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql), instead you can use [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql).

Answer (score 3):

To get only date:

```
DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
```